# Maintain IDE autocomplete when using Object.fromEntries

Tags: typescript

I have an object as follows:

```
const routes: RouteObject[] = [
  {
    id: 'HOME',
    path: '/',
    element: <HomeRoute />
  },
  {
    id: 'ABOUT',
    path: '/about',
    element: <AboutRoute />
  },
];
```

I would like to create a paths object of the following structure (where id is used as the key):

```
const paths = {
  HOME: '/',
  ABOUT: '/about',
};
```

When I use `Object.fromEntries`, I lose autocomplete on the paths object:

```
const paths = Object.fromEntries(routes.map(r => [r.id, r.path]))
```

How can I create a strongly typed paths object from routes? (I would like it to autocomplete `paths.HOME` or `paths.ABOUT`)

Comment: Can you ensure that the `id`s of the input objects would always be "HOME" and "ABOUT"?

Comment: The ids will be fixed. Essentially I require that the id property is used as the property keys inside of the ```paths``` object